# How can I check if radio or checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have this HTML code:

```
   <div id="f4" class="none">

   <h4>Jaký tarif chcete zvolit?</h4>
   <input type="radio" name="tarif" value="tarif1" id="t1"><label for="t1">Tarif 1</label>  <br>
   <input type="radio" name="tarif" value="tarif2" id="t2"><label for="t2">Tarif 2</label>  <br>
   <input type="radio" name="tarif" value="tarif3" id="t3"><label for="t3">Tarif 3</label>  <br>
   <h4>Co chcete aktivovat?</h4>
   <input type="checkbox" name="akt" value="roaming" id="cc1"><label for="cc1">Roaming</label> <br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="akt" value="platby" id="cc2"><label for="cc2">Platby</label> <p></p>

   <input type="button" name="send" value="ODESLAT" onclick="vypisForm();">





   </div>
```

and this is part of vypisForm function:

```
var t1 = document.getElementById("t1").value;
var t2 = document.getElementById("t2").value;
var t3 = document.getElementById("t3").value;
var cc1 = document.getElementById("cc1").value;
var cc2 = document.getElementById("cc2").value;

if(t1.checked) {
   document.write("Zvolený tarif je: "+ t1 + "<br>");
   } else if(t2.checked) {
   document.write("Zvolený tarif je: "+ t2 + "<br>");
   } else {
   document.write("Zvolený tarif je: "+ t3 + "<p></p>");
   }

   document.write("Zvolili jste tyto služby:" + "<br>");
   if (cc1.checked) {
   document.write(cc1 + "<br>");
   } else if (cc2.checked) {
   document.write(cc2 + "<br>");
   } else if(cc1.checked && cc2.checked) {
   document.write(cc1 + "<br>");
   document.write(cc2 + "<br>");
   } else if(!cc1.checked && !cc2.checked) {
   document.write("Žádné");
   }
```

But it does not work.. Idea is that if that radio button is checked, write this and if that radio button is checked write another thing..

Same with the checkboxes, there are two of those..

Does anybody see what I do not?? Thanks

Comment: Well you are referencing the value and you are looking at the checked value of that string..... And you should not use document.write.

Comment: ok thanks.. this is just for checking that I get the right data..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

document.getElementById("t1").value gets the value of the input, but it doesn't hold its checked status. Here is what you want to do.

```
var t1 = document.getElementById("t1");
var t2 = document.getElementById("t2");
var t3 = document.getElementById("t3");
var cc1 = document.getElementById("cc1");
var cc2 = document.getElementById("cc2");
if(t1.checked) {
   document.write("Zvolený tarif je: "+ t1.value + "<br>");
} else if(t2.checked) {
   document.write("Zvolený tarif je: "+ t2.value + "<br>");
} else {
   document.write("Zvolený tarif je: "+ t3.value + "<p></p>");
}

document.write("Zvolili jste tyto služby:" + "<br>");
if (cc1.checked) {
   document.write(cc1.value + "<br>");
} else if (cc2.checked) {
   document.write(cc2.value + "<br>");
} else if(cc1.checked && cc2.checked) {
   document.write(cc1.value + "<br>");
   document.write(cc2.value + "<br>");
} else if(!cc1.checked && !cc2.checked) {
   document.write("Žádné");
}
```

Comment: thanks it works.. but what if I would like to show not value attribute, but label of that radio button?

Comment: If you use the field `for` and `id` for your inputs, you could do:

`if(t1.checked) {
    var label = document.querySelector('label[for='+t1.id+'']';
    document.write("Zvolený tarif je: "+ label.innerHtml+ "<br>");
}`

Comment: when I use your code it says undefined.. and I had to delete one quation mark.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to test for checked on the value.

Instead of:

```
var cc1 = document.getElementById("cc1").value;
```

Use:

```
var cc1 = document.getElementById("cc1").checked;
if (cc1) {
    document.write(cc1 + "<br>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because both `cc1` and `cc2` have to be the checkboxes themsevles not their values:

```
var cc1 = document.getElementById("cc1");
//                                     ^^^ remove .value
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need  the `.value` in the `document.getElementById` just the object, so take the `.value` off and it should work.