# Validating if a checkbox or radio button has been checked

Tags: javascript

The following function detects inputs with the class "required" and checks if they're empty before triggering the submit button and Google ReCAPTCHA.

```
function validate(event) {
event.preventDefault();
//
var questions = document.getElementsByClassName('required');
var valid = true;

for (var i=0; valid && i<questions.length; i++) {
    if (!questions[i].value.trim()) {
        valid = false;
    }
}
if (valid) {
    grecaptcha.execute();
} else {
    alert("Please fill out all required fields.");
}}
```

I'm trying to add a way to detect if a checkbox and/or radio button has been checked off as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: if the type is either radio or checkbox, check `.checked` property. Also, in your current logic, an input with the value of `0` will be marked as invalid.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check if radio or checkbox is checked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44827948/how-can-i-check-if-radio-or-checkbox-is-checked)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the `type` property on the element.

```
for (var i=0; valid && i<questions.length; i++) {
    if (questions[i].type === "checkbox") {
        valid = questions[i].checked;
    } else {
        if (!questions[i].value.trim()) {
            valid = false;
        }
    }

    if (!valid) break;
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!